# ASP.NET How to set Attributes at client side?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to set some data at client side before I send it to server, but it give me no changes

The div contains data:

```
<div id="chanelValues" data-value="0" runat="server"></div>
```

The Checkbox which will give **chanelValues** div it's values

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="dropdownClick(1, 'chanelValues')" />
```

**dropdownClick** func set **chanelValues** **data-value** to 1 success by js

But Server side give me **chanelValues = 0**

```
string chanelValues = this.chanelValues.Attributes["data-value"];
```

How Can I get updated data?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you post back your form to the server? Don't you need a runat=server on your input tag?

Comment: Can you please share javascript code for `dropdownClick`?

Comment: I think the problem did not come from inputs tag

Comment: @Prabhat here's my js code **$('#chanelValues').attr('data-value', newValues);** it work fine

Comment: What is `dropdownClick`? Is this ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Form?

Comment: @NhạHoàng: Are you using simple webform or webform with master page?

Comment: Hi @Win, it's a js function

Comment: We need all the questions in order to solve the problem. Otherwise, we will be shooting the in the dark.

Comment: @NhạHoàng: Let me come to the point. If you are have used webform with master page then this `$('#chanelValues').attr('data-value', newValues);` would certainly won't work as your div id would get changed after page gets rendered into HTML since it is a runat server. [See Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233576/asp-net-onkeyup-event-for-textbox/45234925#45234925)

Comment: @Prabhat, it's value changed, but server side cannot get this value, let's come to my point, first, $('#chanelValues') has **data-value** = 0, after **$('#chanelValues').attr('data-value', 1);**, it's was 1, but the server side code **string chanelValues = this.chanelValues.Attributes["data-value"];** after submitting give chanelValues  = 0 :)

Comment: All things I need is change element attributes then get their current attribute values at the server side!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i get your question wrong but i will try...

You need a model as Interface between Server and Client

```
        using System;

         namespace MvcMovie.Models
         {
                public class Movie
                {
                     public int ID { get; set; }
                     public string Title { get; set; }
                     public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
                     public string Genre { get; set; }
                     public decimal Price { get; set; }
                }
         }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model

```
  @model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

   @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Details";
   }

  <h2>Details</h2>

  <div>
      <h4>Movie</h4>
  <hr />
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
          <dt>
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
          </dt>
           @*Markup omitted for clarity.*@        
      </dl>
  </div>
 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </p>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model

Comment: Thank your MVC code, @hammerthea. Did you try with ASP.NET?

Comment: Yeah i tried it with ASP.NET
if you still have any question just ask or have a look at the links

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [Update TargetID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid.aspx) property

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // you could return a PartialView here if you need more complex HTML fragment
    return Content("<span>some content</span>", "text/html");
}
```

View:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Update div test", 
    "SomeAction", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }
) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but following post is marked under **Asp.Net** and your solution belongs to **PHP**.

Comment: ohh sorry , will try to find a solution in ASP.NET @NhạHoàng