# How to add JavaScript function in c# onkeyup in text box from js file in Web Application

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file `example.js` where I have this function `MultiFR6`:

```
function MultiFR6() {
var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%=txtOddFR6.ClientID%>').value;
var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%=txtStakeFR6.ClientID%>').value;
var result = txtFirstNumberValue * txtSecondNumberValue;
// if (!isNaN(result)) {
document.getElementById('<%=txtReturnFR6.ClientID%>').value = result;
}
```

I want to call this function in the text box of an aspx file.

Comment: put onkeyup="MultiFR6()"

Comment: I am already using this, but not working

Comment: share your code with asp.net control

Comment: where is this control txtOddFR6 ?

Comment: `<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOddFR6" runat="server" Height="60px"  Width="120px"  Font-Size="25" font-bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                   </div>`

Comment: `<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReturnFR6" runat="server" Height="60px"  Width="120px"  Font-Size="25" font-bold="true" type="number"   ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                   </div>`

Comment: `<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStakeFR6" runat="server" Height="60px"  Width="120px"  Font-Size="25" font-bold="true" type="number"   onkeyup="javascript:MultiFR6()" ></asp:TextBox>
                   </div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net onkeyup event for textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233576/asp-net-onkeyup-event-for-textbox)